# 3CX - Call in Waiting with Queue

Tags: sip, voip, pbx, pabx, 3cx

How or where to get call waiting information from 3CX? (For database or api)

[WallBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNehn.jpg)
Awaiting ...

--
Luan

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the default wall board that comes with 3CX then you could look at using [their API](https://www.3cx.com/blog/docs/call-control-api/) to write your own code to gain access to the data you need.

Alternatively there is a Git project called [3cx Wallboard Websocket](https://github.com/CryptoGir/3cx_wallboard_websocket) that uses Ruby to extract data from 3CX in order to insert it into a database.

> Connects to the websocket of the 3cx wallboard and writes data to a
>   mysql database